# Разрешение на отправку сообщений vk api

Tags: php, yii2, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Для того что бы отправить сообщение от имени сообщества нужно:
1.Токен сообщества
2.Разрешение пользователя для отправки ему сообщений.

Все что нашел в апишке это https://vk.com/dev/messages.allowMessagesFromGroup
Однако для использования этого метода нужен scope Messages...

Ощущение что я копаю не в ту сторону. Кто сталкивался, подскажите как получить это самое разрешение от юзера? php

Comment: Вы не сможете написать от группы первым, пока бот не получит событие от этого пользователя, связанное с группой, то бишь, например, вступление в группу, или выход из нее. (или же не сделает подписку на рассылку). Исходя из этого у пользователя по умолчанию ставится параметр, позволяющий писать ему от сообщества, а потом уже может идти речь о методе, вышеописанном вами.

Comment: Ваш метод не что иное, как сама подписка для доступа сообщества к отправке сообщения этому пользователю.

Answer (score 0):

[Виджет](https://vk.com/dev/bizmessages?f=2.3.%20%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%C2%AB%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%C2%BB)

Или

[Чтобы запросить у пользователя разрешение на отправку сообщений, используйте:](https://vk.com/dev/bizmessages_doc?f=2.%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

- Метод [showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox](https://vk.com/dev/clientapi?f=15.%20showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox) Client API в приложениях
  сообществ;
- Метод [messages.allowMessagesFromGroup](https://vk.com/dev/messages.allowMessagesFromGroup) в
  Standalone-приложениях;
- Виджет [«Разрешить писать сообществу»](https://vk.com/dev/AllowMessagesFromCommunity) на
  внешнем сайте.